# jQuery: remove whole parent table

Tags: jquery, button, html-table

I have images in separate tables with Delete button and I would like to remove the table of which delete button was clicked.

I have tried `$(this).closest("table").remove()` and `$(this).parents("table").remove()` but without success. Nothing happens.

Here's the HTML:

```
<table class='".($i % 2 ? "tbl_img_light" : "tbl_img_grey").">
<tr>
<th rowspan='2'>Image here</th>
<td>Description here
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button class='ad_del_img' value='$filename'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It might look  messy, took it out of my PHP loops

```
and JS:
$(".ad_del_img").click(function() {
var file = $(this).val();
dataString = "file="+file;

//$(this).closest("table").remove();

$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'controlUI/bin/delete_image.php',
         dataType : 'json',
         data: dataString,
         success: function(data)
         {
           alert("Success");
           $(this).closest("table").remove();
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
         {
           alert("Error");
         }
       });
return false;
});
```

Comment: you haven't posted any of your JS. there's definitely smoething wrong with your js, because this works: http://jsbin.com/odole3/edit

Comment: Which browser? If FF, check the error console for messages.

Comment: found out the problem just second ago, and yes, it was with my js :P
apparently $(this) doesn't work so well inside ajax call, but I made a work around. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is context isn't maintained by default, but in jQuery 1.4+ you can specify a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), like this:

```
$.ajax({
  context: this,  //add this
  type: "POST",
  url: 'controlUI/bin/delete_image.php',
  dataType : 'json',
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("Success");
    $(this).closest("table").remove();
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error");
  }
});
```

The [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) determines what `this` is when all of your event handlers for the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request run, including `success`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button.ad_del_img').click(function()
{
   $(this).closest('table').remove();
});
```

For me the above code snippet is working perfectlly. If it still doesn't work, the error is probably somewhere else.

Oh, and in this method, the table header doesn't get deleted.......

Comment: edited my JS into the question. does anyone know why $(this) doesn't well inside the ajax thingy? $(this).remove() still removes the button, but it doesn't find the table